# Excel Protected Sheet drop down box to access macro error

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, protected

I am trying to access a drop-down box, to use a certain macros. The drop-down lets me to select units, and the macro changes my inputs too all of those units.

So, when I protect my sheet. I can no long access the drop down box without this error message:

> The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only. To modify a protected cell or chart, first remove protection using the Unprotected Sheet command (Review tab, Changes group). You may be prompted for a password.

I can still change the values in the cells. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unprotect the sheet, format the cell and on the Protection tab untick the "locked" property. Then you can protect the sheet again and the dropdown will work.